# Flare fading when moving camera

Tags: unity, lighting

I have been trying to do a sun in Unity 3D. I have used a sphere with a texture and a flare.

The problem is that when I move the camera the flare fades until it disappears when the sun is almost out of view, as shown in the image:
[image: Flare is gone]
I've tried changing the fade value fron the flare but I can't see any difference.

Does anybody know if this is a normal behaviour or if it can be fixed so the flare is always the same as long as the sun is in view?
Thank you!

Comment: This is the normal behaviour. As the flare crosses the edge of the screen, it gradually fades down to avoid an obvious pop. You can avoid showing a bare sun by adding your own additively blended halo card around / in front of it.

Comment: I see, thank you. Could you please elaborate on how to add the halo or point me to a tutorial? Because I've been trying to add a halo component but I don't see any difference.